# How to get the value of nodes[i].dataset.key

Tags: javascript, php, xml, dom

I have variable called Votes. And its looped like a list view.I want to update a specific raw item value of this varible.For that I use raw number here hard coded 765, and managed to get in. How can i get the value `nodes[i].dataset.key` and increment it

eg: My raw id 765 --> $varible value is 30 --> make it 31

```
    if (nodes[i].dataset.key == 765){
       // i want to go inside using raw ID and update the value display on that raw 
        }
```

Requirement:

I have varibale numVotes in a loop with values. In raw 765 i want to update that value. I already figured to find the exact raw now how to update the varibale value in that raw?

**Update:**

```
<td align="center" colspan="5" class="num_votes" data-key="<?php echo $rawID ?>"><?php echo $votes ?></td>
```

This is what i'm targeting. this is inside a raw.Now if this is raw 765 i want to update the vale **$votes** of that particular raw !

Comment: missing `"` and `>` in td

Comment: typo :| its working but i dunno how to update value

Comment: my question is like how to access variable value using raw id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text content, parse the value, add `1` with the parsed value and re-assign the value.

```
nodes[i].textContent = Number(nodes[i].textContent) + 1;
```

Comment: mm i think i mislead you,it works and it increment the raw ID. mm i want to change the value in that raw ID i will explain and update question a bit to clear

Comment: hehe just you got it i have a small doubt yet ill update you till now +1 :D

Comment: i have another question if i post that can you give some help eeee :D

Comment: @missC :  glad to help you :)